# Is there an API call to check if streaming is enabled for a Real Time Event Monitoring Event (Setup > Platform Tools > Event Manager > Event)?

Tags: api, streaming-api, shield, streaming

So as part of the Salesforce Shield release there is a new Salesforce Settings page at "Platform Tools" > "Events" > "Event Manager".

[image]

As seen in the image above, the Settings page contains a Grid listing various Real Time Event Monitoring Events. Each "Event" has a "Streaming Data" option. Is there way for me to programmatically check if "Streaming Data" is enabled for a specific "Event"?

== Adding response for the first Answer ==

Hi John, thanks for the answer!

Unfortunately the suggested SOQL query did not return results when first run through the Workbench.

[image]

To follow up I created a custom PushTopic and ran the query again. This time it returned one result - the custom PushTopic I had just finished creating.

[image]

Possibly there is a setting that is keeping the “Event Manager Events” from showing up in the PushTopic SOQL query, but right now I am under the impression that the “Event Manager Events” are different than regular Push Topics.

Thanks! any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of 17 Dec 2019 this capability is not supported by Salesforce. However it is on their road map.

src: https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00004ilJqt

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run a SOQL query against the `PushTopic` sObject like the one below.

```
SELECT Description,IsActive,Name,Query FROM PushTopic
```

There's additional fields, but it's the `Name` field that corresponds to Channel. Here's the reference page in Salesforce [Help](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/pushtopic.htm).  It's not exactly an API resource, but with a few lines of Apex you should be able to programmatically check if "Streaming Data" is enabled for a particular "Event".

Why don't you try in this in the Dev Console or Workbench in your Org and see if the results correspond with your screenshot above?

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer!

Unfortunately the suggested SOQL query did not return results when first run through the Workbench.

https://imgur.com/o0kN092

To follow up I created a custom PushTopic and ran the query again. This time it returned one result - the custom PushTopic I had just finished creating.

https://imgur.com/Txjnkp7

Maybe there is a setting that is keeping the “Event Manager Events” from showing up in the PushTopic SOQL query, but right now I am under the impression that the “Event Manager Events” are different than regular Push Topics.

Thanks! any other tips?